# should I split a large data account into smaller ones

Tags: account

I have an account that contains a lot of fields, 30+.

Besides composability, is there any benefit to splitting this account into different accounts?

Will it improve performance/transaction costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main benefit of splitting up accounts is parallelization. Only one transaction can get a write lock on an account at the same time.

If your on-chain program uses one big account for all of its state, and your instructions all write to that account, then the runtime will need to execute all transactions in serial. Serialized execution limits how many transactions can invoke your program in one block.